# New manager asking me to stay (with matching counteroffer) after accepting another job

Tags: job-change

I am an expat living in Germany. I work for one of the most reputed e-commerce companies here. I have been working here since 2 years now. The job is not bad, but management and the CEO have made some really bad decisions in the past that have led to many people leaving the company, resulting in a big chaos now.

I recently got another job offer with significant higher pay and a better scope to learn and improvise my career. I accepted the new offer and handed in over my resignation 3 months back.

Meanwhile my manager left and we got a new one. The new manager wants me to stay very badly, he even matched the salary, he keeps asking me everyday. My new company, although not as big as the one I am currently working in, somehow seems to be very promising.

Now I am confused on what to do. What should I tell my manager, I don't want to sound arrogant. I want to maintain a decent relationship with him.

Any advice?

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/79458/how-do-i-deal-with-my-current-employer-not-respecting-my-decision-to-leave/79469#79469), but you seem to be asking for language to use in a slightly different scenario so not a duplicate as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: "What should I tell my manager?" That you have a new job and he will shortly be your ex-manager. I pity him, be has landed a new job & it is unlikely that he was told that company was in trouble when he hired on. Now he is trying to do what he can - for himself, and for the company. The pay offer is irrelevant, even that is for himself, and for the company. Were you leaving becuase of bad pay? No. So, what difference does it make? You have made a sound decision and found a new job. Now, follow it through

Comment: New manager knows you are leaving. He will fire you later when it is convenient for him (and when you will have harder time getting such good offer as you have now). Also, by accepting counter-offer you are burning bridges in that new company. It is lose-lose. Move on while going is good.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly simple, just stick to your decision and tell your manager that you've already made up your mind. Use some variation on:

> As I mentioned when I [handed in my resignation / gave notice], I've already accepted a new offer and I won't be entertaining a counter offer. My last day will be the X<sup>th</sup>. Now about [project Delta / that email from Karen / your question the other day] ...

Key points are to make it clear that you won't be changing your decisions and to redirect the conversation to a work topic.

You messed up slightly in letting your manager bug you over this every day and not addressing that before, but it's not too late to do so now. Firmly shutting the conversation down a few times should get him to stop asking. If he keeps doing it then it's time to address that directly:

> You keep asking me to reconsider staying and every time I've told you how I've already accepted an offer and I won't be considering a counter offer. You're not going to get a different answer out of me, so why do you keep asking?

This risks starting another meaningless conversation but it's not as direct or rude as a flat "I need you top asking me about this", though you should keep in mind that your manager is the one being rude.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you've made a choice and you're simply trying to not come out of this as the bad guy but the thing is, you don't owe them anything. They wouldn't give a damn if they'd fire you and you'd ask them to re-consider. You think they would? Nah.

> I recently got another job offer with [...] a better scope to learn and improvise my career

You're certain that this new job offer will give you a better ability to learn and progress. Simply tell your current manager that it's time for you to move on and you've made a decision. You appreciate everything the company has done for you but right now you feel that it's simply time to move on and it's a feeling that cannot be reasoned with.

They say that they really want you, but do they really appreciate you anyway? They matched the salary, but didn't bother to go beyond that. Even with a different manager it seems like they try to get away with giving you the minimum they need to keep you, instead of going the extra mile. Maybe not up to the manger but instead upper management or HR, but still an indication that your skills are probably more appreciated elsewhere.

Thank them for everything and you can even say that you hope that your paths will cross again in the future if fate allows.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the better salary, it doesn't sound like anything has changed at your company. And you didn't mention "salary" as a reason for leaving anyway.

You should just continue on with your plans - serve out your resignation period and move on to your new company.

Tel your new manager "thank you, but I have decided to move on".